# Subdomain in Drupal to an already existing site

Tags: domains, subdomain, webserver

I would like to add to an existing site, which wasn't written in Drupal, a sub site, which is in Drupal. The existing site already has a domain, and this would be a sub domain. I'm using Apache2 and Ubuntu 12.04. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are several prerequisites for running Drupal. You can install these with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5-mysql php5-gd libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server
```

Previously installed packages will be skipped.

Unzip Drupal in its own directory. Assuming your top-level site is in `/var/www` and Drupal is in `/var/www/drupal`, you would only need to set the $base_url in Drupal's settings.php to the subdirectory, e.g.:

```
$base_url = 'http://www.example.com/drupal';
```

If you need to place the Drupal installation outside of the domain's directory, you can add an Alias directive to the top-level domain definition in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` (likely a VirtualHost container). If Drupal is located in `/usr/local/drupal`, then:

```
Alias /drupal /usr/local/drupal
```

This will direct Apache to use the physical directory as a site subdirectory.